# Proving a maximum and minimum inequality

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

I'm trying to show that $\min{(x,y)} \le \frac{a}{a+b}\cdot x + \frac{b}{a+b} \cdot y \le \max{(x,y)}$, for all $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$ $>0$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assume $x\le y$. Use $1-\frac{a}{a+b}=\frac{b}{a+b}$ and arrive at $y< x$ if the equality does not hold.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Awesome solution.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x,y\ge\min(x,y)\implies\frac{ax+by}{a+b}\ge\frac{a\min(x,y)+b\min(x,y)}{a+b}=\min(x,y)~~\because a,b>0$

Similarly use the fact $x,y\le\max(x,y)$ to prove the other part.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really helpful!

Comment: You are welcome :)